# How to use a rule such that it substitutes the value x and derivatives of x in the expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

For example, I have gotten the value for a certain function `H[t,r]`:

$H[t,r] \to -\frac{2r(K[t,r]+K^{(0,1)}[t,r]+2m+r+...)}{(2m-r)}$

I want to replace its value, using "rules" in another function that depends on the values ​​of `H[t,r]` and some first or second derivatives on t and r. For exemple:

$F=2m+H[t,r]+H^{(0,2)}[t,r]+H^{(1,1)}[t,r]+...$

When I just use `/. ruleH` Mathematica replaces only the values ​​of `H[t,r]` and does not change the derivatives. Is there a command that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain `H -> Function[{t, r}, G[t, r]]`form, use the following:

```
# /. HoldPattern[y_[x__] -> bodyfunc_] :> 
y -> Function[{x}, bodyfunc] & /@ {yourRule}
```

And then:

```
F /. H -> Function[{t, r}, G[t, r]]
```

Here, $G(t,r)$ is the expression on the right-hand side of your rule:

$$-\frac{2r(K[t,r]+K^{(0,1)}[t,r]+2m+r+...)}{(2m-r)} $$

An example:

```
D[x^3, {x, #}] & /@ Range[3]
(*{3 x^2, 6 x, 6}*)
# /. HoldPattern[y_[x__] -> bodyfunc_] :> 
y -> Function[{x}, bodyfunc] & /@ {y[x] -> x^3}
(* y -> Function[{x}, x^3]*)
{y'[x], y''[x], y''[x]} /. y -> Function[{x}, x^3]
(*{3 x^2, 6 x, 6}*)
```

**Update**: you can use the Resource Function [SolutionRulesToFunctions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SolutionRulesToFunctions/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The short form of your functions since you don't give the whole expression

```
F = 2*m + H[t, r] + D[H[t, r], r, r] + D[H[t, r], t, r]
```

set the rule to include derivatives:

```
ruleH1 = H -> Function[{t, r}, -((2*r*(K[t, r] + D[K[t, r], r] + 2*m + r))/(2*m - r))]
```

then just

```
F /. ruleH1 // FullSimplify
```

or if you like pure functions

```
ruleH2 = H -> (-((2*#2*(K[#1, #2] + D[K[#1, #2], #2] + 2*m + #2))/(2*m - #2)) &)

F /. ruleH2 // FullSimplify
```

Both give the same long expressions.  Either way, to get your substitution to include derivatives, the substitution must be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than answering directly, let me try to you give some background info that will hopefully help you understand this yourself. Suppose you enter an expression such as `f[t]+f'[t]`. Mathematica actually interprets this input as the longer expression

```
Plus[f[t],Derivative[1][f][t]]
```

To see this, just type `FullForm[f[t]+f'[t]]` and it will show you the complete expression that is used internally. Mathematica does not show the `FullForm` by default since that would sometimes lead to awfully long expressions, but when you apply a rule to something and you cannot understand what is going on, you may have to look at the `FullForm`.

**Examples:**

- If you enter `f[t] + f'[t] /. (f[x_] :> x^2)` then `f[t]` is a match but no part of `Derivative[1][f][t]` is a match, and you get `t^2 + f'[t]`.
- On the other hand, if you replace `f[t] + f'[t] /. (f -> (#^2&))` then both occurrences of `f` match the left hand side of the rule, and you get `t^2 + 2*t`.

See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html) for more information.